# What does "/" and "^" mean in ticker symbols? How to translate these symbols into yahoo?

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, yahoo-finance

I have downloaded a complete list of all NYSE stock symbols from the NASDAQ website [here](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx).  As it turns out, many of these symbols are not recognized by the yahoo finance page.  In particular, there are ticker symbols that use "^" and "/" (eg. VALE/A or CTZ^A) which yahoo finance does not recognize.

I've just noticed that, vice versa, yahoo itself has some conventions (eg. adding ".F" or ".SG" to the symbols) that don't appear on the NASDAQ list I downloaded.  Why this incompatibility?  Does anyone know how to "translate" the ticker symbols between the NASDAQ list and the yahoo finance webpage?  I thought these symbols were supposed to be a sort of universal identifier.

Comment: Have you looked into who is supplying the data for these sites?  There is a chance that they may use different delimiters to denote share classes or possibly other components of a stock that may contain special characters that would make it worth noting if there if a FAQ about the tickers listed.

Comment: @JBKing beat me to it, but try replacing them with periods. This is usually used to differentiate between different types/classes of the stock, e.g. common vs. preferred, so some providers will write BRK.A and BRK.B to denote preferred vs. common, while others will write BRK/A and BRK/B. VALE and VALE.P (or VALE/P) are a similar case. Yahoo also uses the `^` to signify indexes, e.g. `^DJI` for the Dow Jones.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a single universal way to reference a stock, there are 4 major identifiers with many different flavours of exchange ticker (see [xkcd:Standards](http://xkcd.com/927/))

- Exchange Ticker, (i.e. What you got from NASDAQ) these are in different formats on each exchange. They are unique within the exchange but the same Ticker can be used on different exchanges maybe even within the same country (although this seems to be rare). Different finance companies (Yahoo, Google, Bloomberg, Thomson Reuters etc.) seem to use different variations of dots, dashes etc. to denote warrants, rights and different classes of shares.
- SEDOLs (my favourite) this is as far as I can tell the only globally unique ID that will never cause you any problems since they identify a specific listed instrument on a specific exchange.
- CUSIPs only unique with a country, only really used in US/Canada
- ISINs like Cusips but with a country code so they can be used globally

I believe CUSIPs and ISINs represent a specific security rather than a specific listed instrument. This means you can have two listed instruments with one ISIN but different SEDOLs because they are listed in different places. The difference is subtle but causes problems with settlement

Specifically on your question (sorry I got sidetracked) take a look at 
[CQS Symbol convention](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=CQSSymbolConvention) to see what everything means

Comment: Actually ISIN is the global unique ID. SEDOL and CUSIP are local identifiers...

Comment: A single ISIN can sometimes map onto one or more SEDOL. For example, Vanguard S&P 500 UCITS ETF is traded on the London Stock Exchange as VUSA (GBP) and VUSD (USD). Both have the same ISIN (IE00B3XXRP09) but different SEDOL (B7NLLS3 and B7NLJN4). Such is the case for many London Stock Exchange-listed ETFs that are traded in multiple currencies.

Answer (score 2):

On NASDAQ the ^ is used to denote other securities and / to denote warrants for the underlying company. Yahoo maybe using some other designators for same.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Answer (score 2):

Nomenclature for stock symbols isn't standardized.  Brokers and web sites use a variety of suffixes for non-standard symbols.  This is particularly maddening for preferred stocks. Fortunately, securities have CUSIP numbers so that other than infrequent human error, ACAT transfers operate efficiently.

To demonstrate the insanity of web site nomenclature for preferred stocks, here's an example for an Alabama Power preferred stock:

```
 QuantumOnline     -       ALP-Q    
 S&P               -       ALP-Q    
 NYSE              PR      ALPPRQ   
 NYSE Amex         p       ALPpQ    
 Bloomberg        /P       ALP/PQ   
 Charles Schwab   /PR      ALP/PRQ    
 E-Trade           p       ALPpQ    
 Fidelity          PR      ALPPRQ   
 Google Finance    -       ALP-Q    
 IBKR              PR      ALP PRQ
 JPMorgan          PR      ALP PRQ  
 LPL Financial     '       ALP'Q        
 MarketWatch      .PR      ALP.PRQ  
 Quicken           PR      ALP PRQ  
 Sharadar         -P       ALP-PQ
 TD Ameritrade     -       ALP-Q    
 Vanguard         _p       ALP_pQ   
 Yahoo!           -p       ALP-pQ
```

Comment: Meanwhile in Canada we would tend to format as `ALP.PR.Q`.

Comment: You're fortunate if they  only use one format in Canada. It's annoying to have so many formats here in the US.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea - Quite a few attractive preferred stocks out there now.  They could even become more attractive when rates rise more.

Comment: Agree. Many perpetuals up here are yielding north of 6% now. There are also many preferred issues here [in Canada] tied to the 5-year Canada government bond rate and many of them are on sale now, too, even though many are bound to reset to a higher coupon over the next few years... assuming no new catastrophes that tank the 5-year yield again.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea - I started adding IG issues around 5.5% - too early but who ever knows that except in hindsight. Have been able to stem the losses with intermittent shorting of the lower yield issues.  It has been a LOT of work to break even :->).  If you are unaware of it, Tim McPartland has a free web site (no agenda) with some really knowledgeable fixed income investors who post.  Despite having owned and traded a Pfds for 20 years, a lot of it is above my head.  But like Stack, you can get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of Tim McPartland and his web site -- I'll check it out. A few years ago I read Doug K. Le Du's good book *Preferred Stock Investing* to learn about the U.S. preferred market. Here in Canada I avidly read James Hymas' published articles and his blog at prefblog.com, though he covers only Canadian prefs. I buy Canadian issues directly and they're a large part of my portfolio, but for exposure to the U.S. prefs market, so far, I'm still using ETFs (PFXF, PFFV) and paying the MERs. I am occasionally concerned about issuer concentration in ETFs, and lack of bargain hunting.

Comment: Regarding preferred stocks, there isn't much in the way of books.  Le Du's book is heads above the rest of them.  The only disagreement I had with him was his delayed exit plan for swapping out of appreciated issues.  What is MERs?  Management expense ratio?

Comment: Yep, I meant the fund fees.